# Concatenating a list of strings

Tags: scala

Is there a built in method to take all of the strings in a list of strings and concatenate them in Scala? If not, how would I do this?

Answer (score 7):

You might be looking for `mkString`:

```
List("a", "b").mkString //"ab"
```

The method also takes in an argument which joins the elements:

```
List("a", "b").mkString(" ") //"a b"
```

Without this method, you could use the more primitive `reduce`:

```
List("a", "b") reduceLeft { (soFar, next) => soFar + next }
List("a", "b").reduceLeft(_+_)
```

Or even the more primitive `foldLeft`:

```
List("a", "b").foldLeft("")(_+_)
("" /: List("a", "b"))(_+_)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that also be `reduceLeft`?

Comment: Indeed, `reduceLeft` is what was intended.  Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

An additional note on `mkString`, you can delimit the beginning and the end of the appended strings, for instance as follows,

```
scala> val x = List("a","b","c")
x: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> x.mkString("<", "-", ">")
res0: String = <a-b-c>
```